# Can I run a Gulp task written in ES6 using Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using ES6 on Node through Babel. I can run ES6 scripts using a `run-babel` script. So, this will work:

```
node run-babel build.js //build.js is written in ES6
```

But now I'd like to access one of these ES6 scripts from a Gulp task but Gulp runs on vanilla node.

Is there a way I can write Gulp tasks in ES6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first go into `node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` and edit the first line to become `#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony`. This will invoke gulp in node harmony mode.

Then you can run `node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build` directly instead of `gulp build`.

You can make an alias if you like :)

Comment: Or you can switch to io.js. It works with gulp and it supports ES6 by default.

Comment: Thanks @LimH, I'll try it right now. As of IO.js... Can I keep using all of my NPM packages if I switch to IO.js?

Comment: @andrerpena sorry I can't say for sure. io.js is compatible with npm but I can't tell whether it is compatible with all of your NPM packages.