# Is it possible write a gulpfile in es6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6

**Question:** How can I write my gulp file in ES6 so I can use `import` instead of `require` and use `=>` syntax over `function()`?

**I can use io.js or node any version.**

---

**gulpfile.js:**

```
import gulp from "./node_modules/gulp/index.js";
gulp.task('hello-world', =>{
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

[image]

Errors:

```
import gulp from "./node_modules/gulp/index.js";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

---

```
gulp.task('hello-world', =>{
                         ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

Inside the `node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` i've changed the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony` as asked in this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836529/can-i-run-a-gulp-task-written-in-es6-using-node)

Comment: as alluded to (but not specifically pointed out in the accepted answer below) the proper syntax for the second example is `gulp.task('foo', () => {...})` this should work in NodeJS 4 and 5 out of the box AFAIK.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, you can by using [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Make sure you've got the latest version of the gulp-cli.

`npm install -g gulp-cli`

Install babel as a dependency of the project.

`npm install --save-dev babel`

Rename `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.babel.js`

Your gulpfile might look something like this:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';

gulp.task('default', () => {
  // do something
});
```

**Update for Babel 6.0+**
As correctly pointed out by [Eric Bronniman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444350/is-it-possible-write-a-gulpfile-in-es6/31444511#comment55087631_31444511), there are a few extra steps involved in getting this to work with the latest version of babel. Here are those instructions:

Again, make sure you've got the latest version of gulp-cli
`npm install -g gulp-cli`

Then install gulp, babel core, and the es2015 presets
`npm install --save-dev gulp babel-core babel-preset-es2015`

Then, either add the following to a .babelrc file or to your package.json

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Your `gulpfile.js` should be named `gulpfile.babel.js`

Comment: After doing this, I get "No gulpfile found" when running gulp.

Comment: @onlywei Make sure you are using the newest version of Gulp, be it globally on your system or locally in your project.

Comment: In Babel 6.x, the ES6 features are opt-in.  See: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1375.  The quick solution is to install the es2015 presets: "npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015", and add a babel configuration block to the package.json.  e.g.  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }

Comment: @EricBronnimann thanks for the tip, updated the answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: I'm still getting "Failed to load external module babel-register" after doing the above steps. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: I was getting an error about parsing the .babelrc , it worked after I set it to the following format: 

{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}

Comment: It could be the problem of sharing `.babelrc`. I fixed it by specify a custom config object for `babel-register`. I simply created a file `gulpfile.js` with `require("babel-register")({
 presets: ["es2015"]
}); require("./gulpfile.babel.js");` and it worked

Comment: @brbcoding why should I rename `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.babel.js`? Can't seem to find anything related in Babel docs... Or is it a Gulp thing?

Comment: UPDATE: as of Babel 6+ the yearly presets have been deprecated and you should use @babel/preset-env https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env
Using the deprecated yearly preset will result in errors on the newest babel versions!

Comment: at the end of 2020 i use these:
`@babel/core`
`@babel/preset-env`
`@babel/register`
`browserslist`
`gulp`

in the .babelrc
`{ "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {"useBuiltIns": "entry }]] }`

Answer (score 6):

Note you can now use many/most ES6 features in Node.js v4.0.0 without babel.  However apparently 'import' is still not supported.  See: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

**Edit**:  Most of the popular ES6 features (including destructuring and spread) are supported by default in NodeJS 5.0 (see above link.)  The only major missing feature appears to be ES6 modules as far as I can tell.

Comment: To use modules you'll have to add the `--harmony_modules` flag.  Destructuring is another IMO popular feature that is still considered 'in progress' as of Nodejs v4.0.0.  Run `node --v8-options | grep "in progress"` to see the full list.

Comment: Ouch, why did I get downvoted?  OP said any io.js or node.js version.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the latest versions of gulp & node, you can simply create a gulpfile as `gulpfile.mjs` instead of `gulpfile.js` and it should work without needing to use Babel or any other transpiler.

`.mjs` is a special format used by node which allows usage of ES Modules.

References :-

- https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling
- https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system

Example :-

```
// Filename: gulpfile.mjs

import gulp from 'gulp';
export default task;

function task()
{
    return (
        gulp.src(`./src/js/**/*.js`)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`./dist/Static/js`)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `babel-node` and native `gulp`.

1. Install `babel` and `gulp` as devDependencies.
2. Write `gulpfile.js` with ES6 syntax.
3. Use command `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/gulp` to run gulp
4. In package.json `scripts` section, you can skip the first `./node_modules/.bin/` part - as `babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/gulp`.

The advantage of this appoach is, one day when the node.js support all ES6 features one day, all you need to opt-out babel runtime is to replace `babel-node` with `node`. That is all.

Comment: One day when node.js will support all ES6 features, babel will support all ES7 features. :)

Comment: I think this is the best approach but you sacrifice the cli benefits, of course you could run tasks from npm scripts pointing to the local binaries

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the most modern version of Gulp and the Gulp CLI, you can just do `Gulpfile.babel.js` and it will understand and transpile your ES6 gulpfile with BabelJS by default.

It is also important to have the BabelJS transpiler installed under `devDependencies` as is Gulp:

```
npm install --save-dev babel
```

Also note that to require gulp in this context, you do not have to import the `index.js`, you can just:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
```

Comment: You should have babel in your `devDependencies` just like `gulp`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It seems not to work. I have *  "devDependencies": {"babel": "^6.5.2","gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",...}* but still get the error point out to `import Gulp from "gulp"` when I execute *gulp* from command line. The file is called *gulpfile.babel.js* too...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need to install using `npm` is `gulp`, `gulp-babel` and `babel-resent-env`, add "env" to your `.babelrc` presets array, and use a gulpfile.babel.js file.

```
npm install gulp-babel --save-dev
```

Some of the answers mentioned `babel-core`, `babel-preset-es2015`, etc. The Babel official **[setup guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/)** with Gulp is to use `gulp-babel` only, while `gulp-babel` has dependencies modules including `babel-core` so you don't need to install it separately.

About preset, you need to use a preset to make Babel actually do something, which is called **[Preset Env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)** that automatically determines the Babel plugins you need based on your supported environments.

```
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

and in `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: This is for adding babel to a gulp project, not writing the actual gulp file in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* 
 *    Steps
 * 1. Rename your gulpfile.js to gulpfile.babel.js
 * 2. Add babel to your package.json (npm install -D babel)
 * 3. Start writing ES6 in your gulpfile!
 */
 
 import gulp from 'gulp'; // ES6 imports!
 import sass from 'gulp-sass';
 
 const sassOpts = { outputStyle: 'compressed', errLogToConsole: true }; // "let" and "const"!!
 
 gulp.task('sass', () = > { // Arrow functions!!
   gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass(sassOpts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
 });
 
 gulp.task('default', ['sass'], () => { // Arrow functions!!
   gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
    .on('change', (e) => {  // Arrow functions!!
      console.log(`File ${e.path} was ${e.type}, running Sass task...`); // Template strings and interpolation!!
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps I followed for developing the code for gulpfile in es6:

- `npm install gulp && sudo npm install gulp -g`.
- Please make sure that you you are using the updated version of Gulp.
  The current version at the time of writing this answer was **3.9.1**. To check which version of gulp is installed, type `gulp -v`
- `npm install babel-core babel-preset-es2015-without-strict --save-dev`
- Type `touch .babelrc` in the terminal
- In the .babelrc file, add this code

  `{
    "presets": ["es2015-without-strict"]
  }`
- Created the gulp config file with the name **gulpfile.babel.js**
- Voila!!! You can now write the config code for gulp in ES6.

**Source:** [Using ES6 with Gulp - Mark Goodyear](https://markgoodyear.com/2015/06/using-es6-with-gulp/)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem and
solved as following:

- Windows 10
- node version: 14.15.4
- npm version: 6.14.10
- gulp version: 4.0.2
- using yarn v1

1. Renamed *gulpfile.js* as *gulpfile.babel.js*
2. Added these packages as devdependency:

```json
"@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
"@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
"@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
"gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
```

3. Added babel.config.json

```json
{
 "presets": [
 [
     "@babel/preset-env",
     {
        "targets": {
            "ie": "10",
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "70",
            "safari": "11.1"
         }
     }
   ]
 ]
}
```

4. Finally I deleted *yarn.lock* file and *node_modules* folder and installed all packages.
   `yarn install`

This is how my *gulpfile.babel.js* file looks like:

```js
import { src, dest, parallel, series, watch } from 'gulp';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import postcss from 'gulp-postcss';
import replace from 'gulp-replace';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import { init, write } from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import babel from "gulp-babel";

//....

const _default = series(
    parallel(scssTask, jsTask),
    cacheBustTask,
    watchTask
);
export { _default as default };
```

**Note:**
`yarn gulp` command runs properly but I still have that warning:
`Requiring external module @babel/register`